# Scala Map: is it possible to update a value of Int with a var of Int?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This feels like a dumb question, but here goes:

Consider the following to update a value of Int in a Map with a var of Int

```
var score: Int = _

val data = Map((
  ("things", "stuff") -> 0),
  (("uwot", "stuff") -> 0),
  (("isee", "stuff") -> 0))

data.map(element => {
  if (element._1._2 == "stuff") {
    score += 1
  }
  element._2 == score
})
```

In place of

```
element._2 == score
```

I've also tried

```
data(element._1).updated(element._1, score)
```

and

```
val result = data.get(element._1)
result == score
```

to no avail

Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Map `data` is immutable and the `element` you get while mapping the Map is also immutable.  You need to assign the result of the `data.map(...)` to a new `val`

`element._2 == score` is a boolean comparison.  It is also the last statement of the map function so you are mapping each element (of type Map[[String,String],Int]) into a boolean, and then not assigning it to anything.

I think what you are trying to get is something like this:

```
val dataOut = data.map( element => {
  if(element._1._2 == "stuff") {
     score += 1
  }
  element._1 -> score
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'd never seen that '->' operator used like that before. What ended up working for my use case was doing a .map on a List then using the "element -> score" to produce a Map with the updated scores